# Is Sequence actually more generic than Iterable, or less so?

Tags: kotlin

Given how a Sequence transformations are lazy (unless terminal) and Iterable transformations are eager (unless you define your own), one could say that accepting Sequence<> as API parameter is a more generic approach than taking Iterable<> - if the API does not care that the data nature is eager or lazy, it can always assume it's lazy (this way it loses nothing if the data it actually eagerly available).

If that is a valid point of view, then it makes sense to design APIs to consume Sequence<> and not Iterable<>. However my boss is pretty confident that Sequence is only used to emphasise the lazy nature of data, which is completely opposite to what I suggested in previous paragraph (to abstract from nature of data).

I wonder what approach language designers had in mind when introducing Sequence. Does this mean "this thing is something which *is* provided lazily" or "this thing is something which *might be* provided lazily"?

Comment: There isn't any obvious "one is better than the other for sequence vs iterable" they're 2 different albeit similar concepts.
For example there's no way to read a sequence twice while you can iterate your Iterable how many times you want. In general being lazy has a cost and makes sense if you need that for some reason, like not knowing how many elements you'll read or so. In general I'd side with your boss. But again this all depends on the use case, you can have the 2 side to side in a codebase.

Comment: @al3c most sequences can be iterated as many time as you want unless it explicitly calls `constrainOnce()`  [Sequence](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence/) [constrainOnce](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/constrain-once.html) :)

Comment: In general you can't know what kind of sequence you have in your hands

Comment: Of course I am implying the API *can* process lazy input. Otherwise there would be little sense in accepting something that is inherently lazy. So, the cost of being lazy is not a problem. On the client side it does not have to be lazy of course, one can just for example do List.asSequence(). So, the question is, am I making API more generic or less generic by using Sequence<>.